# How to get the code to recreate a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, reflection, metaprogramming

I have some dataframe object.

I want to see the code that recreates that dataframe object.

For example, here is my dataframe

```
str(ror)
# 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ from: Factor w/ 2 levels "x","x1": 2 1
#  $ to  : Factor w/ 2 levels "x2","y": 1 2
```

I want to get the following code to be printed by calling some function such as: `recreate(ror)`

```
recreate(ror)
# data.frame(from = c('x1', 'x'), to = c('x2', 'y'))
```

I remember that there was a function to get this code from `ror`, but I cannot find the exact name of this function or exact term to search in google to find it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That was it. But its output is not clean. I guess there was only `dput` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
recreate <- function(DF) {
  res <- textConnection("foo", "w")

  dput(lapply(DF, 
              function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x), 
       control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger"), file = res)

  close(res)

  foo <- sub("list", "data.frame", foo, fixed = TRUE)

  parse(text = paste(foo, collapse = "\n"))[[1]]
}

newDF <- recreate(iris)

all.equal(eval(newDF), iris)
#[1] TRUE

print(newDF)
#data.frame(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
#    5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 
#    5.1, 5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 
#    5.2, 5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 
#    4.8, 5.1, 4.6, 5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 
#    6.6, 5.2, 5, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 
#    6.1, 6.3, 6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 
#    6, 5.4, 6, 6.7, 6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5, 5.6, 5.7, 
#    5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 
#    6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 5.7, 5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 
#    6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 
#    6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 
#    6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 
#    3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 
#    3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
#    3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 
#    3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 
#    3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 
#    3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 
#    2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 
#    3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 
#    3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 
#    3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 
#    3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
#    2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
#    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 
#    1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 
#    1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 
#    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 
#    1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 3.5, 
#    4.2, 4, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 4.7, 
#    4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 
#    4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 
#    4.1, 6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 
#    5.3, 5.5, 5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 
#    5.7, 6, 4.8, 4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 
#    5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 
#    5.4, 5.1), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
#    0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 
#    0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
#    0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 
#    0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 
#    1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
#    1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 
#    1, 1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 
#    1.2, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 
#    2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 
#    2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 
#    1.9, 2, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 
#    1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8), Species = c("setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
#    "setosa", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", 
#    "versicolor", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", 
#    "virginica"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, [`dput`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) is usually an elegant solution:

```r
x <- dput(head(iris))
#> structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
#>     Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
#>     1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
#>     0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
#>     1L), levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
#> 6L), class = "data.frame")
x
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>